# jquery highlight part of asp.net gridview row

Tags: jquery

I have an asp.net gridview, which renders the following table structure:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr>
<tr><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td><td>cell3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am using the following jQuery statement to highlight the entire row for each non-header row.

```
$("table tr:has(td)").css({ background: "ffffff" }).hover(
  function () { $(this).css({ background: "#FC6" }); },
  function () { $(this).css({ background: "#ffffff" }); }
);
```

How would I alter this code to highlight each non-header row but not the 3rd (last) cell of the row?  e.g simultaneously highlight the first two cells of the row, but not the 3rd.

If anyone has a decent web reference for the selector logic, that would be appreciated also.

Comment: If you hover over the last cell should the others highlight as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) combined with the [:last-child() selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), like so:

```
$("tr:has(td)").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("td:not(:last-child)").css("background-color", "#FC6");
}, function() {
    $(this).find("td").css("background-color", "#FFF");
});​
```

This would give the added benefit of not being tied to three columns as well.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhayden1/gtw8t/1/) that demonstrates this.

Comment: I removed theader and tbody elements from your fiddle, as those are not output by the asp.net gridview.  Either way, good answer.  You get the points.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CG9d2/1/), Kindly let me if i am not rite..

```
<table>
<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr>
<tr><td class="c1">cell1</td><td class="c2">cell2</td><td>cell3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="c1">cell1</td><td class="c2">cell2</td><td>cell3</td></tr>
</table>

$(".c1").closest('td').css('background-color', 'red');
$(".c2").closest('td').css('background-color', 'red');
```